# How to count specific cells based on a column and row criteria in a set of Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I am trying to count the number of times a certain value appears in a data set based on a column and row criteria.

For the below set of Data assuming the data covers `A1` to `E6`:

| Team | Chris | Emily | Dan | Bob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| Job 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| Job 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| Job 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Job 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

I would like to create a formula which would be able to look into this data set to find the cells which correspond to Chris, Job 2 and values greater than 2.

Can anyone please advise on this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` to do this but usually get an error. I should get a value of 2. Hope this makes sense

Example of my sumproduct: `=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A6="Job 2")+(A1:E1="Chris")>0)*(A1:E6=">2"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6="Job 2")*(INDEX(A1:E6,,MATCH(TRUE,A1:E1="Chris",0))>2))
```

Or more universal in `B15`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B12)*(INDEX(A1:E6,,MATCH(TRUE,A1:E1=B13,0))>B14))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Count With Multiple Criteria

- As an alternative, that's exactly what `COUNTIFS` does.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6,"Job 2",INDEX(B2:E6,,MATCH("Chris",B1:E1,0)),">2")
```

- Of course, the hard part here is to come up with the `INDEX/MATCH` formula.
- That being said, I prefer the solution in the first answer because `COUNTIFS` only works with ranges so you won't see it in the continuation of the post.
- If you wanna go all fancy about it using Microsoft 365, you can do something like...

```
=LET(d,A1:E6,n,"Chris",j,"Job 2",gt,2,
    dn,DROP(TAKE(d,1),,1),v,DROP(d,1),
    dj,TAKE(v,,1),dv,DROP(v,,1),
    i,INDEX(dv,,XMATCH(n,dn)),
IFNA(SUM((dj=j)*(i>gt)),""))
```

... which is, of course, overkill (madness) in this particular case. Yet it is a base for creating a spilling formula for all members as illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image]

**In `G2`**

```
=LET(d,A1:E21,j,J2,gt,K2,
    dn,TOCOL(DROP(TAKE(d,1),,1)),v,DROP(d,1),
    dj,TAKE(v,,1),dv,DROP(v,,1),
HSTACK(dn,MAP(dn,LAMBDA(r,
    LET(i,INDEX(dv,,XMATCH(r,dn)),
IFNA(SUM((dj=j)*(i>gt)),""))))))
```

- Hopefully, `J2` and `K2` contain drop downs, not to mention, if you put the data in an Excel table when you would be really killing it, all dynamic and flexible...

**A Bug or Am I Blind?**

- I would appreciate it if someone could figure out why `BYROW` (instead of `MAP`) doesn't work in this case: it shows all zeros in the count column. I lost quite some time before I tried `MAP`.